# dumpe2fs only displays one-line message

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am currently working on a virtual machine. I would like to see the super block and blocks group information of my file system.
But when I entered

```
dumpe2fs -bh /dev/sda1
```

only a one-line message was displayed.

```
dumpe2fs 1.44.1 (24-March-2018)
```

/dev/sda1 is in ext4 file system

I just started to learn Linux so please tell me if there is other information I need to provide.

**UPDATE**

What I am expecting is the detail information of the superblock or bad block (if there is one), such as Inode count, free Inodes and blocks, etc.

Comment: Please do not post images of text. Just post the text. What did you expect to happen instead? Is something wrong with the one line that was displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Looks like](https://github.com/tytso/e2fsprogs/blob/master/misc/dumpe2fs.c#L726) options `-b` and `-h` are exclusive - `dumpe2fs` either prints badblocks or superblock information. Because `-b` takes "precedence" over `-h` (is checked in `if(...) else` first.....), the utility prints badblocks, because your filesystem has no badblocks, you only see one line that is always printed. Use `-b` and `-h` separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation! Using `-h` individually does print out superblock information! I haven't notice that there is such logical relation in bash command. Thanks again for the new knowledge.

Comment: `such logical relation in bash command` bash is bash, it's the shell, `dumpe2fs` is not a part bash, it's a separate program developed and shipped by someone else, unrelated to bash. The only "relation" there is is that _you_ are using bash to run that program.